# Trouble adding to hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I am reading a file replacing data and returning output to json. When I try to add a new item to the hash I get the following error. `Not a HASH reference` When I use `ref()` I am getting `HASH` as the type.

I have tried.

```
my $json_data = decode_json($template);
$json_data->{CommandCenters}{NewItem} = ["haha","moredata"];
```

Gives the `not a hash reference` error

The `$json_data` is below.

```
  {
     "Location":"Arkansas",
     "CommandCenters": [
          {
          "secretary": "jill",
          "janitor": "mike"
          }
       ],
  }
```

I am looking for the following output after I add the element.

```
{
  "Location":"Arkansas",
  "city": "little rock"
  "CommandCenters": [
   {
      "secretary": "jill",
      "janitor": "mike"
   },
   {
       "NewItem":["whatever","more data"]
   }
   ],
}
```

If I use `$json_data->{CommandCenters}[0]{NewItem} = ['whatever','sure'];` I do not get an error but I get unexpected results.
The data is added but in the incorrect slot.

```
"commandcenters":
 [
    "secretary":"jill",
    "janitor": "mike",
     "newitem": 
     [
        "whatever","sure"
     ],
 ]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add a new element to an array, use [push](http://p3rl.org/push). As we
're dealing with an array reference, we need to dereference it first.

```
push @{ $json_data->{CommandCenters} }, { NewItem => ["haha", "moredata"] };
```

Answer (score 6):

> When I try to add a new item to the hash I get the following error. `Not a HASH reference` When I use `ref()` I am getting HASH as the type.

Attention to detail is a vital skill for a successful programmer. And you're missing something subtle here.

When you use `ref()`, I assume you're passing it your `$json_data` variable. And that is, indeed, a hash reference. But the line that generates your `Not a HASH reference` is this line:

```
$json_data->{CommandCenters}{NewItem} = ["haha","moredata"];
```

And that's not just treating `$json_data` as a hash reference (`$json_data->{...}`) it's also treating `$json_data->{CommandCenters}` as a hash reference. And that's where your problem is. `$json_data->{CommandCenters}` is an array reference, not a hash reference. It's generated from the bit of your JSON that looks like this:

```
"CommandCenters": [
  {
    "secretary": "jill",
    "janitor": "mike"
  }
]
```

And those `[ .. ]` mark it as an array not a hash. You can't add a new key/value pair to an array; you need to `push()` new data to the end of the array. Something like:

```
push @{ $json_data->{CommandCenters} }, { NewItem => ["haha", "moredata"] };
```

That will leave you with this data structure:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'CommandCenters' => [
    {
      'janitor' => 'mike',
      'secretary' => 'jill'
    },
    {
      'NewItem' => [
        'haha',
        'moredata'
      ]
    }
  ],
  'Location' => 'Arkansas'
};
```

And `encode_json()` will turn that into the JSON that you want.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  New to perl, someone left so I have to fill in.